# how to add scrolling for kendo menu?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, kendo-ui, telerik-reporting, kendo-menu

I have kendo menu( @(Html.Kendo().Menu()) in my web page.When the user reduce the size of web browser user cannot see all the menu items.Can i add scrolling for this menu?

Answer (score 0):

No, the Kendo UI Menu doesn't support automatic scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

They menu will stack l->r t->b if placed in a element that sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to create kendomenu

```
$("#menu").kendoMenu({
    scrollable: {
        distance: 20
    }
});
```

For further information :

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/menu/configuration/scrollable